# Trying to add button to a VBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to create a simple program for rock paper scissors but I am having trouble adding anything to the pane. I when I do pane.getChildren().add(goButton); it doesn't compile and says that it cannot be applied. I'm sure it is simple but my code looks the same compared to what I see online.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Application {

//    private String[] answers = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};
//    private TextField userOutputTF, compOutputTF;
//    private Button goButton;
//    private Label title;
//    private VBox pane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Rock, Paper, Scissors");

        VBox pane = new VBox();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        String[] answers = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};

        Button goButton = new Button("Go");
        pane.getChildren().add(goButton);

        TextField userOutputTF = new TextField("Enter rock, paper, or scissors");
        TextField compOutputTF = new TextField("");

        compOutputTF.setEditable(false);
        userOutputTF.setEditable(true);

        goButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("Handled Lambda listener");
            System.out.println("Have fun!");
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public void Deal() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using AWT controls.
Change the imports to use javafx controls, you'll also need to change the button listener:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Sample extends Application {

//    private String[] answers = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};
//    private TextField userOutputTF, compOutputTF;
//    private Button goButton;
//    private Label title;
//    private VBox pane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Rock, Paper, Scissors");

    VBox pane = new VBox();
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    String[] answers = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};

    Button goButton = new Button("Go");
    pane.getChildren().add(goButton);

    TextField userOutputTF = new TextField("Enter rock, paper, or scissors");
    TextField compOutputTF = new TextField("");

    compOutputTF.setEditable(false);
    userOutputTF.setEditable(true);

    goButton.onMouseClickedProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println("Handled Lambda listener");
        System.out.println("Have fun!");
    });

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public void Deal() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

You also need to add the VBox to some other container inside the FXML or just add it to the root.